# Facebook Application: Block direct access from domain

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

ı have a facebook application and it works on facebook or directly on domain.

but ı dont want it.

**www.mydomain.com/myapp // this shouldnt work.**

you should go:

**apps.facebook.com/myapp**

sorry for bad english .

can anyone help me, ı will be glad.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent facebook canvas app from being accessed directly/outside of facebook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295741/prevent-facebook-canvas-app-from-being-accessed-directly-outside-of-facebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the url do a redirect to where you want the user to go:

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] != "apps.facebook.com")
{
header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp');   
}
```

And if you only want your domain.com and apps.facebook.com

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] != "apps.facebook.com" && $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] != "mydomain.com" )
{
header('Location: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp');   
}
```

or via .htaccess in the folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or simply put in top of your php pages

```
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] != "apps.facebook.com")
{
echo "Error please visit my apps via facebook";
return   
}
```

Comment: ı have more pages like http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/x,y,z.php when user visit myapp/x.php what will happens?

Comment: if someone visit mydomain.com/myapp, ı dont want him to access app. redirect or show error like (you need to go facebook first) how can ı do that.

Comment: With a .htaccess that will protect all the folder

Comment: His `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` won't be apps.facebook.com unless he's on Facebook's own servers (i.e. never).

Comment: What are you talking about ceejayoz? The server name is the domain and yes it's working

Comment: Why would the server name be apps.facebook.com unless it's an FBML app?

Comment: I fully agree with ceejayouz. The code above is not correct in this sitionation: $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'domain_the_php_is_running_on'.

Answer (score 0):

There's not going to be a good way to check for an apps.facebook.com frame because of the `Same-Origin Policy`. I'd recommend just going the route of detecting if you are in a frame at all in javascript like this:

`if(window == window.top) window.top.location='http://apps.facebook.com/whatever/';`

It won't prevent someone else from iframing you but at least your domain would redirect you to the Facebook page.